# Adding (and exporting) tags to pictures

Tags: photos, geotagging

I am trying to find a way to organize picture metadata in my Android phone. By default, it adds location and time data, so that the photos are easily searchable on the phone. I can also tag people and the software recognizes faces and suggests people name.

Unfortunately, it seems that both people name and location data are not available when I donwload the photos on my computer. The metadata should be written in the photos in EXIF, IPTC and/or XMP format, so that other tools on my computer will recognize them.

Also, I can only tag people when the software recognizes that there is a face, and many photos of people are not correctly recognize as such.

Is there some way I can tag and organize pictures, storing the metadata correctly in the photos themselves?

Comment: I read in the FAQ. "Basically, what problem (with your Android device) are you trying to solve?" Well, I am trying to solve the problem of tagging photos and exporting metadata. I am not asking for a recommendation in the sense that there are many options available and I am looking for the best one. I am asking how to perform a specific task, possibly with the use of existing apps

Comment: I have removed the explicit request for an application. Really, it is not about recommendations. It is about a specific task to be completed on Android. If that requires installing some third party application, so be it

Comment: OK, that's a possibility (I've removed my close-vote ;) Still, SR might be the better place asking for an app. I'm not aware of any built-in feature that could be used here – but there are some apps dealing with EXIF tags, though I'm not sure how far they cover your needs. // For now: Shall we delete above comments for a cleanup?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some application that can help me tag and organize pictures, 
>   storing the metadata correctly in the photos themselves?

I do not know any android app that can do this.

But maybe you can help implementing this feature

Unfortunately the android internal media database/media scanner does not support "tags" for photos
so an android app has to implement the tag scanning/management on its own.

I also donot know a ready to use android java library that can write jpg iptc-tag infos.

currently i am thinking about adding tag-support to https://github.com/k3b/AndroFotoFinder/
using a pc generated csv file to transfer tags

For details see https://github.com/k3b/AndroFotoFinder/issues/25

[Update 2016-11-09]

Implementation is under way using a seperate [xmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) - [sidecar file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidecar_file) for every jpg to store the iptc-tags.

There is much work ahead for this hobby project.

On the pc side you have to use an exiftools based batchfile to transfer between non-android-standard-jpg-fields and xmp-sidecarfile/csv

[Update 2016-11-09]

Implementation is done :-) with tag write support in jpg-exif or external xmp file